# How to custom sort a list of strings given a desired sorting hierarchy?

Tags: c#

I would like to sort a `List<string>` in a particular way. Below is a unit test showing **the input**, **the specific way** (which I am calling a "hierarchy" - feel free to correct my terminology so that I may learn), and **the desired output**. The code should be self explanatory.

```
[Test]
public void CustomSortByHierarchy()
{
    List<string> input = new List<string>{"TJ", "DJ", "HR", "HR", "TJ"};

    List<string> hierarchy = new List<string>{"HR", "TJ", "DJ" };

    List<string> sorted = input.Sort(hierarchy); // <-- does not compile. How do I sort by the hierarchy?

    // ...and if the sort worked as desired, these assert statements would return true:
    Assert.AreEqual("HR", sorted[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("HR", sorted[1]);
    Assert.AreEqual("TJ", sorted[2]);
    Assert.AreEqual("TJ", sorted[3]);
    Assert.AreEqual("DJ", sorted[4]);
}
```

Comment: Providing a unit test for your question is such a great idea. More people should do that.

Comment: I completely agree. So much easier to help someone if they structure it this way.

Comment: @sapbucket - Please don't add answers to your question. If you have an answer add it as an answer. You are welcome to answer your own question. It is good etiquette not to accept your answer if someone's else's answer is correct. If you want to post your answer as an answer you'll find the source in the revisions link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
var hierarchy = new Dictionary<string, int>{
    { "HR",  1},
    { "TJ",  2},
    { "DJ",  3} };

var sorted = strings.OrderBy(s => hierarchy[s]).ToList();
```

Comment: That worked perfect. Please see my edit in the original posting for the complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to do this.

It's not great to create a static dictionary - especially when you have a static list of the values already in the order that you want (i.e. `List<string> hierarchy = new List<string>{"HR", "TJ", "DJ" };`). The problem with a static dictionary is that it is static - to change it you must recompile your program - and also it's prone to errors - you might mistype a number. It's best to dynamically create the dictionary. That way you can adjust your `hierarchy` at run-time and use it to order your `input`.

Here's the basic way to create the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> indices =
    hierarchy
        .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.value, x => x.index);
```

Then it's an easy sort:

```
List<string> sorted = input.OrderBy(x => indices[x]).ToList();
```

However, if you have a missing value in the `hierarchy` then this will blow up with a `KeyNotFoundException` exception.

Try with this `input`:

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "TJ", "DJ", "HR", "HR", "TJ", "XX" };
```

You need to decide if you are removing missing items from the list or concatenating them at the end of the list.

To remove you'd do this:

```
List<string> sorted =
    input
        .Where(x => indices.ContainsKey(x))
        .OrderBy(x => indices[x])
        .ToList();
```

Or to sort to the end you'd do this:

```
List<string> sorted =
    input
        .OrderBy(x => indices.ContainsKey(x) ? indices[x] : int.MaxValue)
        .ThenBy(x => x) // groups missing items together and is optional
        .ToList();
```

If you simply want to remove items from `input` that aren't in `hierarchy` then there are a couple of other options that might be appealing.

Try this:

```
List<string> sorted =
(
    from x in input
    join y in hierarchy.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
        on x equals y.value
    orderby y.index
    select x
).ToList();
```

Or this:

```
ILookup<string, string> lookup = input.ToLookup(x => x);
List<string> sorted = hierarchy.SelectMany(x => lookup[x]).ToList();
```

Personally, I like this last one. It's a two liner and it doesn't rely on indices at all.